# Web API 2 Caching

Tags: caching, asp.net-web-api2, cache-control

We have a requirements that some Web API responses should never be cached .

When we checked the headers in the response of a Web API 2 calls , we found that there is no Cache-Control headers.

Does this mean that Web API 2 results are not cached by default or do we need to send the header **Cache-Control : no-cache , no-store** will every response to ensure that results are not cached

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not cached by default.

If you want to use caching,you need to write logic or include libraries for it.

Comment: Ok... thanks , Any idea if the absence of cache control headers will lead to caching

Comment: I don't think that if cache control headers are missing, it will cache the data.